# Extract only color in css file

Tags: c#, css

How can I extract only the color in a CSS file?

- I made an attempt but it only extracted the first 2 colors in the CSS file
- I don't know which loop I should to use

My code:

```
    private void btnLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string cssString = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            var match = Regex.Match(cssString, @"color: (.+?);").Value;
            var match2 = Regex.Match(cssString, @"background-color: (.+?);").Value;
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `Regex.Matches`? Also, there are other color properties - using a color pattern match may be better than trying to pick out properties.

Comment: I think you're looking for Matches. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.

Matches will return a MatchCollection, which will contain all matches in the input text.

Comment: This MatchCollection works.Thanks men